# Passing custom webcomponent, as parameter of a custom webcomponent

Tags: polymer

Hi I want to make a Webcomponent like in Google Inbox. Where the messages are.

A big table and when i click on a row it becomes bigger with extra informations and actions. How could I make it so that the datas are parsed from a json file and there are multiple "selectedTemplate" and i can put them into the json as a variable to tell the table "you have to open this row with this template".

**UPDATE**

I tried and i have now a code like this one:

```
 <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
     <div layout vertical>
          <core-animated-pages> 
               <section>
                    <paper-shadow class="chain">
                        {{item}}
                    </paper-shadow>
               </section>
               <section>
                    {{item.artists}}
               </section>
          </core-animated-pages>
      </div>
</template>
```

The problem is I want to create a structure where i have a list and i can animate each item of the list with hero transitions. But if i make it like this then all items get on top of each other... What should I do?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't even know if it is possible, to make it like i want... I made the template component i want to make open but you don't need it to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. Look on [core-animated-pages](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages) especially *chip to card demo*

Comment: I tried it but i need a way like in inbox so when i make one row "opened" then the previous and next rows has to been shown too above and after the selected row just with some extra space between them. With core-animated-pages it hides the other rows when one is selected.